# Extract bounding box points from IAM paragraph xml file

Tags: python, computer-vision

[image]

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
import glob
import sys,os

classes = ['line']
xml_dir = "annots/"
output_dir = "labels/"
image_dir = "images/"

index=0
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(xml_dir, '*.xml'))
for file in files:
    base_name = os.path.basename(file)
    filename = os.path.splitext(base_name)[0]
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(image_dir, f"{filename}.jpg")):
        print(f"{filename} image does not exist!")
        continue
    print(f'form {file}')
    width, height = int(root.attrib['width'])//2, int(root.attrib['height'])//2
    root = ET.parse(file).getroot()
    xmin, ymin = [sys.maxsize] * 2
    xmax, ymax = [0] * 2
    ftxt = ''
    result = []

    for line in root.findall('.//line'):
        txt,id = line.attrib['text'],line.attrib['id']
        txt = unescape(txt, {"&apos;": "'", "&quot;": '"'})
        ftxt = ftxt + txt + '\n'

        for cmp in line.findall('.//cmp'):
            dm = list(map(int,[ cmp.attrib['x'],cmp.attrib['y'],cmp.attrib['width'],cmp.attrib['height']]))
            print(f'xmin = {xmin} , dm = {dm[0]}')
            xmin = min(xmin,dm[0])
            print(f'just got xmin of:  {xmin}')
            ymin = min(ymin,dm[1])
            xmax = max(xmax,dm[0]+dm[2])
            ymax = max(ymax,dm[1]+dm[3])
            
        # devide by 2 because image has been downsampled by a factor of 2
        pil_bbox = [xmin//2, ymin//2, xmax//2, ymax//2]
        yolo_bbox = xml_to_yolo_bbox(pil_bbox, width, height)
        bbox_string = " ".join([str(x) for x in yolo_bbox])
        result.append(f"{index} {bbox_string}")

        if result:
            with open(os.path.join(output_dir, f"{filename}.txt"), "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write("\n".join(result))
```

I am trying to find the bbox points for each line from this Iam dataset file. I get the lower bounds correct but the upper bound seem to be not updating, specifically the y1 and y2 values with the code above.
can anyone give it a shot for me? image attached and xml below: note: the cordinates at the end should be devided by 2 because the image has been downsampled by a factor of 2

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE form SYSTEM 'http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~fki/iamdb/form-metadata.dtd'>

<form created="2002-01-15" height="3542" id="b04-208" last-modified="2002-07-17" skew="30" status="final" version="3.0_beta" width="2479" writer-id="114">
  <machine-printed-part>
    <machine-print-line text="At the beginning of this wonderful century many people believed that there were no" />
    <machine-print-line text="more worlds to conquer." />
  </machine-printed-part>
  <handwritten-part>
    <line ass="-691" asx="0" asy="518" character-width="999" dss="-691" dsx="0" dsy="706" fd0="12676" fd1="2502" fd2="-1099" filter-width="3" id="b04-208-00" lbs="-763" lbx="0" lby="611" segmentation="ok" slant="87000" stroke-width="4877" threshold="182" text="At the beginning of this wonderful century many" ubs="-549" ubx="0" uby="580">
      <word id="b04-208-00-00" sentence-start="yes" tag="IN" text="At">
        <cmp x="358" y="561" width="34" height="75" />
        <cmp x="392" y="565" width="33" height="71" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-01" tag="ATI" text="the">
        <cmp x="465" y="557" width="96" height="74" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-02" tag="NN" text="beginning">
        <cmp x="614" y="527" width="36" height="103" />
        <cmp x="647" y="576" width="78" height="134" />
        <cmp x="731" y="580" width="8" height="11" />
        <cmp x="738" y="586" width="47" height="42" />
        <cmp x="790" y="590" width="71" height="39" />
        <cmp x="858" y="571" width="9" height="8" />
        <cmp x="869" y="592" width="80" height="127" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-03" tag="INO" text="of">
        <cmp x="999" y="598" width="35" height="39" />
        <cmp x="1031" y="555" width="40" height="158" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-04" tag="DT" text="this">
        <cmp x="1115" y="565" width="85" height="76" />
        <cmp x="1208" y="590" width="24" height="53" />
        <cmp x="1210" y="582" width="10" height="8" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-05" tag="JJ" text="wonderful">
        <cmp x="1296" y="572" width="43" height="67" />
        <cmp x="1339" y="557" width="132" height="75" />
        <cmp x="1476" y="556" width="56" height="149" />
        <cmp x="1538" y="591" width="44" height="41" />
        <cmp x="1589" y="563" width="28" height="64" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-06" tag="NN" text="century">
        <cmp x="1679" y="573" width="77" height="57" />
        <cmp x="1763" y="558" width="24" height="78" />
        <cmp x="1793" y="585" width="101" height="113" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-00-07" tag="AP" text="many">
        <cmp x="1950" y="577" width="65" height="61" />
        <cmp x="2023" y="593" width="20" height="30" />
        <cmp x="2040" y="586" width="62" height="47" />
        <cmp x="2106" y="589" width="27" height="117" />
      </word>
      <lower-contour>
        <point x="356" y="714" />
        <point x="928" y="719" />
        <point x="2087" y="719" />
      </lower-contour>
    </line>
    <line ass="-383" asx="0" asy="713" character-width="999" dss="-383" dsx="0" dsy="851" fd0="12678" fd1="2659" fd2="-1157" filter-width="3" id="b04-208-01" lbs="-414" lbx="0" lby="800" segmentation="ok" slant="90000" stroke-width="4888" threshold="182" text="people believed that there were no more worlds to" ubs="-321" ubx="0" uby="764">
      <word id="b04-208-01-00" tag="NNS" text="people">
        <cmp x="356" y="737" width="61" height="118" />
        <cmp x="418" y="779" width="26" height="29" />
        <cmp x="453" y="733" width="45" height="114" />
        <cmp x="500" y="741" width="41" height="60" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-01" tag="VBD" text="believed">
        <cmp x="605" y="718" width="60" height="90" />
        <cmp x="670" y="729" width="51" height="73" />
        <cmp x="720" y="758" width="5" height="4" />
        <cmp x="729" y="760" width="65" height="46" />
        <cmp x="798" y="734" width="62" height="77" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-02" tag="CS" text="that">
        <cmp x="921" y="730" width="34" height="82" />
        <cmp x="959" y="729" width="29" height="80" />
        <cmp x="993" y="775" width="24" height="34" />
        <cmp x="1018" y="741" width="54" height="67" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-03" tag="EX" text="there">
        <cmp x="1119" y="720" width="146" height="91" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-04" tag="BED" text="were">
        <cmp x="1300" y="758" width="44" height="57" />
        <cmp x="1349" y="766" width="82" height="42" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-05" tag="ATI" text="no">
        <cmp x="1489" y="752" width="33" height="73" />
        <cmp x="1517" y="772" width="31" height="39" />
        <cmp x="1552" y="777" width="25" height="35" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-06" tag="AP" text="more">
        <cmp x="1624" y="748" width="69" height="72" />
        <cmp x="1696" y="785" width="20" height="29" />
        <cmp x="1720" y="769" width="47" height="44" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-07" tag="NNS" text="worlds">
        <cmp x="1819" y="763" width="88" height="56" />
        <cmp x="1909" y="747" width="31" height="64" />
        <cmp x="1934" y="782" width="20" height="15" />
        <cmp x="1953" y="733" width="30" height="83" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-01-08" tag="TO" text="to">
        <cmp x="2031" y="740" width="38" height="78" />
        <cmp x="2064" y="777" width="22" height="30" />
      </word>
      <upper-contour>
        <point x="356" y="714" />
        <point x="928" y="719" />
        <point x="2087" y="719" />
      </upper-contour>
      <lower-contour>
        <point x="357" y="855" />
        <point x="629" y="855" />
      </lower-contour>
    </line>
    <line ass="-2630" asx="0" asy="910" character-width="999" dss="-2630" dsx="0" dsy="1023" fd0="13343" fd1="2856" fd2="-650" filter-width="3" id="b04-208-02" lbs="-372" lbx="0" lby="980" segmentation="ok" slant="87000" stroke-width="4844" threshold="182" text="conquer." ubs="-7148" ubx="0" uby="887">
      <word id="b04-208-02-00" tag="VB" text="conquer">
        <cmp x="359" y="929" width="42" height="58" />
        <cmp x="378" y="929" width="4" height="7" />
        <cmp x="401" y="929" width="48" height="53" />
        <cmp x="460" y="953" width="29" height="92" />
        <cmp x="498" y="942" width="85" height="44" />
      </word>
      <word id="b04-208-02-01" tag="." text=".">
        <cmp x="618" y="980" width="10" height="12" />
      </word>
      <upper-contour>
        <point x="357" y="855" />
        <point x="629" y="855" />
      </upper-contour>
    </line>
  </handwritten-part>
</form>
```